# Zoom on mouse position

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I have a feature and on click I want to zoom in (basically the same functionality as if I use the mouse wheel at this position). However (and that's pretty clear), it always uses the center of the map as the center of the zoom which makes my feature move away from the mouse position.
How can I scroll programatically on the position of the mouse?

That's the code I use on the onClick event:

```
map.getView().fit(this.feature.getGeometry(), {
    duration: 300,
    maxZoom: 18,
});
```

Again: it's clear to me that it does what it does - but what can I do instead?!

Thanks for any ideas!
Sebastian